# DMAX Formula not Working Properly

Tags: excel-formula

I have the following formula with the intention of finding the most recent date in the "DATE" column of a Table that matches the input inventory # in the "INV #" column:

```
=IF(J6="","",IF(COUNTIF(RecordsTable[INV '#],J6)>0=TRUE,DMAX(RecordsTable,5,DMAX_Crit),"None"))
```

"J6" Contains a whole number, the Inventory # I am looking up (ex. 4040)

"DMAX_Crit" is the named range where I have placed my Criteria. The range is 2 cells and it looks like this:

__**AQ**

**1** INV #

**2** =J6

When I put an Inventory # into "J6", I expect this to check and see if that Inv. # exists in the "INV #" column, and if it does, then return the most recent date associated with any instance of that Inventory # in the "DATE" column (column 5).

What this is actually doing is returning *A* date from the "DATE" column, but not one associated with the Inventory #, and not even the most recent date out of all the records that currently exist.

I currently have 3 records in the Table:

**INV #......DATE**

4040.......10/15/2016

1310........9/22/2016

1377........9/22/2016

If I put a non-existing Inventory # into "J6", the formula properly returns "None", however if I put 4040, 1310, or 1377, the formula returns "9/22/2016", no matter which I put in - not even the most recent date in the list. I checked to see that my value in "J6" is properly transferring to my DMAX_Crit Range, and it is.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you managed anything other then `0` from your formula (possibly because your data layout is not quite what I have interpreted it to be - an image might help) but this does appear to do what I think you want it to:

```
=IF(J6="","",IF(COUNTIF(RecordsTable[INV '#],J6)>0=TRUE,DMAX(RecordsTable[#All],5,DMAX_Crit),"None"))
```

The difference is just insertion of `[#All]`.